# SQL if else stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I'm writing a stored procedure and it's working for if but not for else.  For if I'm getting the correct ID value but for else it's just giving me null.

```
SELECT  @ID = ID FROM PRODUCTS WHERE SN = @SN
SELECT @Chip_ID = Chip_ID FROM PRODUCTS WHERE SN = @SN
SELECT @Power = Power From Module_Cycle WHERE ChipID = @Chip_ID

SELECT @Test_ID=Test_ID FROM TestEE_Mod WHERE ID=@ID AND @TypeID = TypeID
IF(@Test_ID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN

    IF(@TypeID = '3')
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @Temp_TestID=TestID FROM TempCycle WHERE ChipID = @Chip_ID AND @Power = 'false'
        BEGIN
            UPDATE TestEE_Mod SET Temp_TestID = @Temp_TestID WHERE ID = @ID AND TypeID = @TypeID
        END
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @Temp_TestID=TestID FROM TempCycle WHERE ChipID = @Chip_ID AND @Power = 'true'
        BEGIN
            UPDATE TestEE_Mod SET Temp_TestID = @Temp_TestID WHERE ID = @ID AND TypeID = @TypeID
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: check whether Test_ID FROM TestEE_Mod returning null or blank and print @TypeID  to check the value, other wise your else statement is correct

Comment: On an unrelated note, why are your `UPDATE` statements surrounded in their own `BEGIN...END` block?

Comment: @JonSenchyna I thought I needed them but I removed them now.  I'm new to SQL that's why still in the learning process. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the issue lies in the `@Power` variable.  In your two `SELECT` statements, the only difference is that one includes `@Power = 'false'` in the `WHERE` clause, while the other includes `@Power = 'true'`.

Since `@Power` is a variable, not an actual column in your `TempCycle` table, I'm guessing you actually meant to filter by `Power = @Power` in both of them.

Comment: I removed @ from @Power and now it works.  Didn't notice it until now.  lol Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  If this is the correct answer, please mark it as so.